# Laravel 5.1 Eloquent collection not returning correct results

Tags: json, eloquent, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade, laravel-collection

I have an eloquent collection `{{ $questions }}`, when i output it inside a blade template i get the following results:

```
[{"question_num":0,"survey_id":2,"question_text":"test","expected_answer":1},
  {"question_num":1,"survey_id":2,"question_text":"test","expected_answer":1}]
```

As you can see there are exactly two objects. Now when I apply this 
filter `{{ $questions->where('question_num','=', 0) }}`, I get the following results which is correct:

```
[{"question_num":0,"survey_id":2,"question_text":"test","expected_answer":1}]
```

But when I apply the following filter `{{ $questions->where('question_num','=', 1) }}`, I get an empty result, why is that, when clearly the collection has a question_num with value of 1?

```
[]
```

I've been scratching my head all day with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you use operator, here but Collection signature for `where` method is:

```
where( string $key, mixed $value, bool $strict = true)
```

so in both cases, you should use:

```
{{ $questions->where('question_num', 0) }}
```

and

```
{{ $questions->where('question_num', 1) }}
```

to get result you expect

Comment: So why does the following still return null: `{{ $questions->where('question_num', 0)->get('question_text' }}`?

Comment: In the end i've had to this: `{{ $questions->where('question_num', 0)->first()['question_text'] }}` unless anyone know a better way to do it?

Comment: @ozzii Get method is not what you want to use here. You want probably use `pluck` here. But assuming you might get multiple values from `where` you should rather not use `first()` unless you are 100% sure you will always have only 1 element. You might be interested in using for example: `questions->where('question_num', 0)->pluck('question_text')->all()` and you will get here array containing all values from `questions_text` column with question_num=0